# how to remove terraform kubernetes resources and kubernetes cluster in single run

Tags: terraform

I have CI/CD pipeline which runs `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` on each commit I do to my repo.

I created something like following:

```
module "gke" {
  source                   = "registry.terraform.io/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google"
  ...
}

...

module "workload_identity" {
  source              = "registry.terraform.io/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/workload-identity"
  cluster_name        = module.gke.name
  ...
  depends_on = [
    module.gke.endpoint
  ]
}

...

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.gke.endpoint}"
  ...
}

...

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "main" {
  metadata {
    ...
  }
  ...
  depends_on = [
    module.gke.endpoint
  ]
}
```

If I'll remove all this code in single commit it will fail on plan stage because of multiple reasons:

- `kubernetes_ingress_v1.main` will not be able to access cluster to delete it
- `module.workload_identity` will also not be able to access cluster because it has some kubernetes resources inside.

I can do it in multiple commits, but I wonder if there is a way to fix a code to make `plan` work?

Comment: How would ingress delete the cluster?

Comment: @MarkoE  I guess Mateusz tries to say that kubernetes_ingress_v1.main will not be deleted because terraform tries to destroy Kubernetes resources at the same time with ingress resource destroy. I feel like depends_on does not work properly since module.gke.endpoint is just output.  Mateusz, can you change module.gke.endpoint to module.gke in depends_on meta arguments?

Comment: Yeah, I was honestly interested because that would mean there's something awfully wrong with Kubernetes provider. :) And I agree with your comment about changing the `depends_on`.

Comment: `depends_on` is indeed path forward here.